# EXC_BAD_ACCESS with ABPeoplePickerNavigationController

Tags: ios5, automatic-ref-counting, addressbookui

Code works fine in Xcode Simulator, but when I tested it on real device, app hangs with error:
**EXC_BAD_ACCESS, (code 1, address 0x0)**

```
ABMultiValueRef multi = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);
NSString* contactEmail = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multi, 0);
CFRelease(multi);
```

Upd.: Works on iPhone also, if contact has email field filled. If not, it crashes.

Comment: OK, check for quantity prevents from crashing.
    if (ABMultiValueGetCount(phones) > 0) {
        contactPhone = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multi, 0);
    }

Answer (score 0):

OK, checking for zero prevents from crashing.

```
if (ABMultiValueGetCount(phones) > 0) {
    contactPhone = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multi, 0);
}
```